# Asp.net mvc Creating a new record

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've been trying to add a new record.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {


       var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
      ViewData["CustomerID"] = TempData["CustomerID"];
        var a = dc.services.Select(arg => arg.ServiceID).ToList();
        ViewData["ServiceID"] = new SelectList(a);
       var model = new Maping();

        return View(model);
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Customerservice/Create

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude ="CustomerServiceMappingID")]  Maping serviceToCreate)
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View();

       var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
       dc.Mapings.InsertOnSubmit(serviceToCreate);

           dc.SubmitChanges();

           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");



    }
```

Now the situation is that the tempdata has the correct value but by the time i submit changes the customerID turns out to be null. So, kindly help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAI understand you copy the customer id from TempData to ViewData. However, the contents of the ViewData will be not preserved after the request ends. In your view you should put the customer id into an input (e.g. a hidden field if it should be not displayed) to get it back in your post action.
If you use a strongly typed model, you should not use the ViewData at all, but rather you should set the customer id on the model instance. Then in the view you could use a `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerId)` to "preserve" this id.
I hope I did not misunderstand the question, unfortunately it is not really visible in your code snippets where you would have a customer id in the post action that is null.